# Missing "DockerVersion" field value when inspecting docker image after build by Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-image

I have built a docker image through Dockerfile with the `docker build` command. If I check the generated image with the `docker inspect` command, then I can see an **empty "DockerVersion" value**.

```sh
$ docker build -t myimage:latest .
$ docker inspect myimage:latest
```

```json
...
"Container": "...",
"ContainerConfig": {
    ...
},
"DockerVersion": "",
"Author": "",
"Config": {
...
```

This occurs not just for a specific `Dockerfile` but for all `Dockerfile` built on my local environment.

I built docker images on a **Mac** and the Docker Engine version is **20.10.8** (Docker Desktop).

`Dockerfile` is a very simple file with only a few lines with no special content.

The build was also executed with `docker build -t xxxx:xxxx .` without any special features.

Have any of you ever had this kind of experience?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens also on the images build on my Windows 10 machine with Docker Desktop running under WSL2. And it's a normal behavior.

Those fields, like `DockerVersion`, `Author` and so on, are part of the Docker images, but they're not used anymore as they're not part of the standard for open containers.

On the opposite, the Open Containers Initiative (OCI) [has defined a standard set of annotations](https://github.com/opencontainers/image-spec/blob/main/annotations.md#pre-defined-annotation-keys) to use in all the image manifests.